# Anonymous users cannot initiate multipart uploads. Please authenticate

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I get following error -

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Anonymous users cannot initiate multipart uploads.  Please authenticate.</Message>
<RequestId>0C687E53286678DE</RequestId>
<HostId>eqEEEENy6phBYvOySn3gOsbk9wJYjbE/yWK6MBtmR0M4Ir0TEdh9SfApX/EdZZ6sZ7Mc/wSwh0U=</HostId>
</Error>
```

When I make a call to AWS API to initiate multi-part upload from JS - I have added PutObjectACL as well in my policy as suggested by other users in other discussions. However I still keep getting this error -

Following is the policy that I have -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PutObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/sampleFile/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using following ajax call and am also passing Authorization in the header -

```
var url = 'https://bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/sampleFile?uploads';

j$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type:"POST",
            headers: formHeadersToBeUploaded,
            processData:false,      
            contentType:false,
           success: function() { 
                alert('Successful while submission');  
            },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {  
            console.log('Error while sending ' + xhr, status, error);
            }
        }); // END OF AJAX
```

Authorization is -

AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ACCESSKEYID/20160331/us-east-1/service/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=authorization;host;x-amz-date,Signature=09caa362719e578cb48699bbc5bd4e4089335fb56806653186e782ba009ff3a5

Thanks any help is really appreciated

Comment: *am also passing Authorization in the header* ... which is the one thing you're not showing us.  Please show, for example, the captured request headers.  S3 doesn't think you are even *trying* to authenticate, so at this point, your policy statement is not the issue -- it's not being evaluated.

Comment: The only thing potentially noteworthy, now, is that you are missing the expected space after the commas, immediately before `SignedHeaders=` and `Signature=`.  I don't know if that's significant, but it is different than the examples.

Answer (score -1):

The anonymous principal is just "*".  Also, I wouldn't grant Listbucket to anonymous unless you want everybody seeing your bucket.  Also, you want to make sure you control of the object.  Also, with multipart upload you want to enable a life cycle policy to delete failed uploads.

When you the bucket owner requirement the upload needs to include the canned all bucket-owner-full-control with the CLI it looks like

```
aws s3 cp hello.json s3://bucketname/sampleFile/hello.json --no-sign-request --all bucket-owner-full-control
```

S3 Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PutObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/sampleFile/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To Clean up incomplete multipart upload go the buckets Management tab and create a new Lifecycle.  There is an option to "Clean up incomplete multipart uploads" after a set number of days.